# BoneCP with JSF Spring Hibernate Configuration

Tags: spring, hibernate, bonecp

I tried to use BoneCP with my JSF-Spring-Hibernate combination, following BoneCP configurations on their website.

I am using Intellij as IDE and i added framework supports directly into project but BoneCP and its needed libraries are taken from maven.

Here is my simple spring-config.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="user" />

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <!-- Don't forget to list all your entity classes here -->
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>user.model.User</value>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Spring bean configuration. Tell Spring to bounce off BoneCP -->
<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy">
    <property name="targetDataSource">
        <ref local="mainDataSource" />
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- BoneCP configuration -->
<bean id="mainDataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ch?characterEncoding=utf8" />
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="1234"/>
    <property name="maxConnectionsPerPartition" value="60"/>
    <property name="minConnectionsPerPartition" value="20"/>
    <property name="partitionCount" value="3"/>
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="10"/>
    <property name="statementsCacheSize" value="50"/>
    <property name="releaseHelperThreads" value="3"/>
</bean>

<!-- Enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

<!-- Transaction Manager is defined -->
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

When i am running project on Tomcat 7, it gives me these errors :

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mainDataSource' while setting bean property 'targetDataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource] for bean with name 'mainDataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1628)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mainDataSource' while setting bean property 'targetDataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource] for bean with name 'mainDataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource] for bean with name 'mainDataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1262)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:433)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:257)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1283)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1254)
    ... 45 more

Ara 09, 2012 5:24:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mainDataSource' while setting bean property 'targetDataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource] for bean with name 'mainDataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1628)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mainDataSource' while setting bean property 'targetDataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource] for bean with name 'mainDataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource] for bean with name 'mainDataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1262)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:433)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:257)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1283)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1254)
    ... 45 more
```

BoneCP classes are not found. How can i fix it ? I am using bonecp-provider 0.8.0-alpha1 hibernate 4 spring 3 jsf 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource is in the core jar file so you don't need the -provider jar at all.

Also make that -rc1 instead of -alpha1.

Comment: it is true that there is a version -rc1, but it is not easily foundable on web , i.e mvnrepository still shows the alpha version.

Also, i downloaded all the jars into my local library with dependencies like guava and sl4j.

Honestly, i think i could not correctly configure maven, there must be an easy and smart way with maven.

thank you for your help

Comment: Like all recent versions, rc1 is in maven central.

Answer (score 1):

You don't only need the -provider but the bonecp-version.jar (e.g. [this one](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/jolbox/bonecp/0.7.1.RELEASE/bonecp-0.7.1.RELEASE.jar)) as well.
I am not sure where you got the .8 alpha version but there must be an analogous jar there as well.

Edit: missed that you were using Maven. Then simply copy your dependency definition

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.jolbox</groupId>
  <artifactId>bonecp-provider</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.0-alpha1</version>
</dependency>
```

into

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.jolbox</groupId>
  <artifactId>bonecp</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.0-alpha1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yes currently I am using these dependencies. Anyway, it is noticed that you have to use 0.8.0-alpha1 if you want to work with hibernate 4.

I wonder that it may be about local library and maven confusion. Because i am using spring and hibernate from local library. BoneCP and providers coming from maven. May be i have to use all of them in local jars.

Comment: can you post your pom.xml?

Comment: i solved the case with downloading all jar files to my local library, with using version 0.8.0-rc1

thank you for your answers.